# Cross-platform pipe command in NPM script

Tags: node.js, npm, pipe, npm-scripts, coveralls

Considering we have NPM script with a pipe, similarly to what's suggested in [Istanbul documentation](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls#istanbul):

```
"coveralls": "cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls"
```

It obviously doesn't take Windows into account.

How can such command with a pipe be made cross-platform in Node.js package?

The question is specific to Coveralls but isn't limited to it; this could be any command with a pipe.

Comment: Can you do this programmatically with node?  I know that's overkill for a simple pipe command, but it will at least guarantee cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Bash and the Windows command line (e.g. *cmd.exe* and *PowerShell*) have the pipe operator (`|`) so that shouldn't be a concern regarding cross-platform compatibility.

Given your example npm-script, the primary incompatibility regarding cross-platform support is usage of Bash's [`cat`](https://ss64.com/bash/cat.html) command. Usage of `cat` will fail via Windows *cmd.exe*, however `cat` is supported via Windows *PowerShell*.

To circumvent the aforementioned cross-platform issue regarding `cat`, consider  utilizing a *nodejs* utility script as follows. Let's name the file `cat.js`:

**cat.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function(err, data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

As you can see, it utilizes nodes builtin:

- [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) to read the contents of a file.
- The file path of the file to read will be provided as an argument to the script and captured using [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).
- The contents of the file is the written to [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

<sub>**Note:** For the sake of brevity `cat.js` doesn't include any error capturing/handling, so you may wish to add some.</sub>

**npm script**

Then in your `scripts` section of your *package.json* we invoke `cat.js` and pass the path to the file (i.e. `./coverage/lcov.info`) as an argument. For instance:

```js
"scripts": {
  "coveralls": "node cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls"
},
```

<sub>**Note:** The npm-script above assumes `cat.js` resides in the same directory and level as *package.json*. If you choose to locate it elsewhere the path to it will need to be redefined. E.g. `"node path/to/cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ..."`</sub>

So long as the *nodejs* file specified on the right hand of the pipe (`|`) utilizes [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) to read from `stdin`, i.e file descriptor `0`, (as [coveralls.js](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls/blob/master/bin/coveralls.js) does) using the pipe cross-platform will be OK.

Comment: I tried to avoid custom scripts if possible because they defy the purpose of using NPM scripts. If there's a script, it's tempting to move everything to it. Thanks for `cat` example, I just discovered https://github.com/shelljs/shx , I suppose `shx cat` will be drop-in replacement.

Comment: Yes `shx cat` is an ideal replacement. Interesting, I found it too tempting a while back and now all custom build logic and tooling reside in a separate _.js_ script - analogous to what _eslint_ do in [package.json](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/package.json) and [Makefile.js](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/Makefile.js). I use [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) methods extensively in the _.js_ script to address cross-platform. _npm-script's_ alone were becoming too cryptic, non-human readable,  lacked commenting, lacked customization of logic, etc...

Answer (score 1):

While I have not used Windows in some time, its CMD.EXE command line processor supports command redirection as well as “piping” the output of one program to the input of another.

See [Syntax Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more information.

For piping programmatically, see the [pipe-operator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pipe-operator) NPM module for a Node/JavaScript implementation of shell piping.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the main problem here is `cat`, as suggested in another answer. I suppose windows native counterpart would look very different and possibly without `|`.

Comment: Under Windows, the `type PATH` can be used to pipe the contents of a file to another program.

Answer (score 1):

### About

We have made a package exactly for this:
https://github.com/cpuabuse/cross-cat

A cross platform `cat` command, behaving exactly like linux `cat` command. You can call it as `cat` or `cross-cat` from a script. It works with windows `cmd` and `coveralls` as well.

### Install

```
npm install cross-cat --save-dev
```

### Use

```
"scripts": {
    "coveralls": "cross-cat coverage/lcov.info | coveralls"
}
```